# Имитировать перенос строки для обновления рядов данных

Tags: java, консоль

Нужно подавать в консоль обновление данных, как несколько строк. Проблема в очистке консоли (Linux/Windows) и невозможности удаления предыдущей строки.

Как решение, хочу сымитировать перенос строки и вытирать все, как одну строку.

Пример данных в консоли для обновления:

```
Список слов:
эпсилон
глюон
синергия
крем
полдень
```

То есть, пользователь должен видеть только обновление, без предыдущих значений сверху нового результата в консоли.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать `clear` в Linux , `cls` в Windows?

Comment: @LEQADA
Да, это как вариант, но я не нашел подходящего решения.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл вот такое интересное решение.

```
public static void clearScreen() {  
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
}
```

Решение основано на [управляющих последовательностях ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI).
`\033[H` перемещает курсор на позицию 1:1 (левый верхний угол). `\033[2J` очищает всё окно терминала.

[Оригинал](http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2014/12/clear-command-line-console-and-bold.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Работает хорошо! еще бы как-то курсор переместить в конец первой строки...
Но все таки, все предыдущие данные остаются в консоли сверху, хотя не видно, к ним можно прокрутить...

Comment: @CodeGust, в Ubuntu команда `clear` работает так же. Очищает окно, но к предыдущему можно всегда прокрутить. Не думаю, что возможно иначе.

Comment: Получается, очистить точно нельзя полностью. 
Значит, остается или использовать Ваш вариант очистки и найти способ переместить курсор на первую строку, или все таки как-то отформатировать строку, что бы выглядела как несколько строк...

Comment: @CodeGust, вы можете манипулировать курсором, как хотите. Прочитайте об [управляющих последовательностях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI#CSI_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B)

Comment: Разве Windows консоль поддерживает управляющие последовательности?
т.е. для переноса курсора на первую строку я вывожу в принт "\015[1F" ?

Comment: @CodeGust, а вы протестируйте код под Windows. У меня нет возможности это сделать. Думаю, что поддерживает. Нет, для переноса курсора нужно использовать `\033[n;mH`, где `n` - строка, а `m` -  столбец.